# Create a count matrix of actor names from movies

Tags: python, matrix, count, nlp, countvectorizer

I have a dataframe with 2 columns i.e. UserId in integer format and Actors in string format as shown below:

```
Userid               Actors

u1     Tony Ward,Bruce LaBruce,Kevin P. Scott,Ivar Johnson, Naomi Watts, Tony Ward,.......
u2     Tony Ward,Bruce LaBruce,Kevin P. Scott, Luke Wilson, Owen Wilson, Lumi Cavazos,......
```

It represents actors from all movies watched by a particular user of the platform

I want an output where we have the count of each actor for each user as shown below:

```
UserId  Tony Ward Bruce LaBruce Kevin P. Scott Ivar Johnson  Luke Wilson Owen Wilson Lumi Cavazos
u1          2           1              1              1            0          0            0
u2          1           1              1              0            1          1            1
```

It is something similar to countvectoriser I reckon, but i just have nouns here.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its a `pandas.Dataframe` try this, [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) Transform each element of a list-like (result of `split`) to a row [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) aggregates the data & [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) transforms to required format.

```
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.replace(",\s", ",").str.split(",")

(
    df.explode('Actors').
        groupby(['Userid', 'Actors'], as_index=False).size().
        unstack().fillna(0)
)
```